# JOIN performance very slow when selecting VARCHAR field

Tags: mysql, performance, heidisql

I have a difficult problem with a query which I can't find out why it is performing so bad.

Please see following queries and query times (using HeidiSQL):

```
SELECT p.TID, a.TID
FROM characters AS p JOIN account a ON p.AccountId = a.TID;
```

> => rows: 57.879  Query time: 0.063 sec. (+ 0.328 sec. network)

Explain:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+-----------+-------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref       | rows  | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+-----------+-------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | index | TID           | WebAccountId | 5       | NULL      | 21086 | Using index              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | ref   | AccountId     | AccountId    | 5       | dol.a.TID |     1 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+-----------+-------+--------------------------+
```

---

This is fast but as soon as I select a VARCHAR(255) field from table `characters` it gets very slow. See network time.

```
SELECT p.TID, a.TID, p.LastName
FROM characters AS p JOIN account a ON p.AccountId = a.TID;
```

> => rows: 57.879  Query time: 0.219 sec. (**+ 116.234 sec. network**)

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+-----------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref       | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+-----------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | index | TID           | WebAccountId | 5       | NULL      | 21086 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | ref   | AccountId     | AccountId    | 5       | dol.a.TID |     1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+-----------+-------+-------------+
```

Query time is still good but network time got unbearable.

---

One could think that its caused by the transfer of `p.LastName` but see the query *without the join*:

```
SELECT p.TID, p.LastName
FROM characters AS p
```

> => rows: 57.881 Query time: 0.063 sec. (**+ 0.578 sec. network**)

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 59800 |       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------+
```

Any idea what is going on here? I have no idea how to fix that.

**Edit:**
Added the Explain output for each query.
In case it matters, it's mysql 5.1.72-community

**Edit2:** Tested from commandline. Same performance. If I look into the mysql process list I see `Sending data` for the poor performing query. The query was originally used in a ASP.NET web application before and performance was very bad. That is why I used HeidiSQL to investigate. I would definitely rule out HeidiSQL as the problem.

**Edit3** Test result in Mysql Workbench:
[image: Mysql Workbench]

Comment: Have you tried running this query command line from your PC.  That would narrow down if it's just HeidiSQL or if it's the JOIN/network.  Personally, it looks fine to me unless you're returning tens of thousands of rows.   My money is something wonky with your Heidi ..   Try it in Workbench?

Comment: Can you post EXPLAIN output of both queries?

Comment: Is `account.TID unique`?

Comment: Are the columns in your join indexed?

Comment: Edit your question and add the schemas of the two tables.

Comment: @Uueerdo Yes account.TID is primary key.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Yes TID is primary key in both tables.

The thing here is that the query itself is fast. I see that in process list. With the join the SQL process is in "sending" state all the time. Will do the queries on command line if wished but I doubt mysql will react different. 

All tests were made versus a local database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out what was the culprit here. I used mysql 5.1.72 with InnoDB on default settings.

This means it used an InnoDB buffer pool of just 8MB

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8M
```

Mysql was forced to write the result to disk as it couldn't hold it in memory for transfer as soon as I added the VARCHAR fields to the select clause. The Join seems to have pressured the memory usage of that buffer even more.

After I changed the buffer size to 1G the problem was gone.

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G
```

The first request after mysql start can still be a bit slow but subsequent queries are very fast.

[image]

**So it was basically misconfiguration of the mysql server.**